# Changing the separate arrow image

Tags: 2010, branding

I'm trying to change the separate arrow image.

[image]

Currently what is putting this image there is:

```
   <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
```

What I need to know is how can I override this so that instead of using the default arrow, it will use an image that I specify.

All I've been able to find so far tells me to just hide this and put the image I want as the background, but I would rather be able to override the control, as can be done with the smallsearchinputbox to change the icon for the search.

If anyone has any information about this or is able to point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create your own path seperator.

Follow this blog - [Improving Navigation in SharePoint 2010 — Part 1](http://bguidinger.com/blog/2012/01/improving-navigation-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1/)

In the `PathSeparatorTemplate` insert your own seperator or seperator control.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain CSS to solve this I think, like this:

```
.s4-titlesep img {
  display: none;
}
.s4-titlesep {
  background-image: url(http://goo.gl/jHKdF);
  background-size: 11px 11px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```